# Issue with loading TempData into DropDownListFor c# mvc .net core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a rather large form that submits Visits, Insurance info, and procedure info. I need to be able to navigate away from the form to create new patients, physicians, insurance etc if they are not currently present. When I am redirected back to the form I need to retain the form data plus whatever new data was added. Currently I am using TempData to keep the values of each individual property in my model. I then refer to the TempData value to populate the "value" field in my inputs. This works fine for all my field including text and date time, but the drop downs are giving me a problem. I am using a viewbag to populate the DropDownListFor, and the closest I can get to achieve what I want is to replace the 3rd parameter in the DropDownListFor with my TempData(The default value) and set a hidden field with my TempData value. This is far from rock solid and very buggy. I want the dropdown lists to behave like my text and date time inputs, but there is no "value" attribute with a DropDownListFor. Does anyone know how I can achieve the equivalent of "value" in a text input within the context of DropDownListFor?
This is the DropDownListFor in my view

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="InsId" class="control-label">Insurance</label>
    <a style="padding-left:18px;">
       <button asp-controller="Insurances" asp-action="IndexSV" asp-route-id="@ViewBag.NextVisitID" class="btn btn-primary fa fa-plus-circle" style="background-color:#16a085;"></button>
    </a>

    @if (TempData.Peek("InsId") != null)
    {
         var InsName = (string)ViewBag.InsIdName;

         @Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => modelItem.InsId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Insurances, InsName, new { style = "width:80%;" })
         <input type="hidden" asp-for="InsId" class="form-control" value="@InsuranceId" />
         <span asp-validation-for="InsId" class="text-danger"></span>
    }
    else
    {
        @Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => modelItem.InsId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Insurances, "--SELECT--", new { style = "width:80%;" })
        <span asp-validation-for="InsId" class="text-danger"></span>
    }
</div>
```

And this is how I'm getting my data in the controller

```
ViewBag.Insurances = _context.Insurance.Select(p => new SelectListItem { Value = p.InsId.ToString(), Text = p.InsCarrierName }).ToList().OrderBy(x => x.Text);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, see https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp - the selected option tag in a select has a selected attribute.  this is set by the value of the first parameter in DropDownListFor, `modelItem.InsId` in your case. Set that value appropriately before rendering.  Take a look at this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PdyOeI) - the select value is set here `public int SelectedProductId { get { return 2; }}`.

Comment: This ended up being the solution I was looking for, thanks!                                                  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.VisitProcCode, new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem { Text = PatClass, Value = VstPatClass.ToString() } }.Concat(new SelectList(ViewBag.Class, "Value", "Text")), new { style = "width:80%;" })

Comment: I'm sorry if my reply was misleading, but I didn't use your solution. I used the solution I provided. I just meant thanks for the reply. I still learned from your solution, so I'll mark as accepted. I think it's HILARIOUS that I get three negative votes, yet you're the only one who attempted to offer a solution. Thanks again!